# Is it possible to make my Angular URLs cleaner than this?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

So I have an angular webpage and we have the following types of URLs

```
/category/:c_link
/job/j:link
```

and I was wondering if it would be possible to remove the identifying piece(category and job) and somehow retain the ability to recognize the difference between.

```
/:c_link
```

and

```
/j:link
```

they are different fields in my database, but I haven't come accross a way to differentiate the two.
The end purpose is to have a better quality link for a link building campaign.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

p.s.

I'm not a native english speaker, so please excuse any spelling errors ;)

Comment: What's the `identifying piece`?

Comment: the `category` and `job` bit.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what a job link and a category link look like?

Comment: For example: `category/plumber` and `job/unclog_drain`

Comment: What (logically, technically) prevents the same piece of text from being applied to both a job and a category?

Comment: Well, technically nothing so far(thats exactly what I'm trying to figure out ;)). Logically `plumber` and  for instance `handyman` would be categories under which jobs as `unclog_drain` and `hang_lamp` would fall. There is nothing to identify this by, while just looking at the string.